# How can I split an attribute value onto two lines?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an asp.net app, and I'd like to split a line like the following on to two lines (I'd like to manually wrap the line)

```
<table style="border: thin solid #808080; padding: 3px 5px 7px 5px; vertical-align:top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

Ideally, I'd like to see something like this:

```
<table style="border: thin solid #808080; padding: 3px 5px 7px 5px; "
                + "vertical-align:top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

But of course the + operator doesn't work here.

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Just take into a new line. It is OK.

Comment: @Joe Because I'm a curmudgeon and I think code that extends beyond the right hand side of the window should be wrapped nicely; because I hate having to side-scroll to see what all the arguments are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an operator. The whitespace and linebreak will be ignored.

```
<table style="border: thin solid #808080; padding: 3px 5px 7px 5px;
              vertical-align:top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

You should consider using CSS files though instead of inline styling.

Comment: Perfect. Re using CSS files... I agree, but I prefer to slay one dragon on this project at a time, thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

Move the styles into a css file or style tag. Give the table a class name and reference it that way. Done.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Hit: [Ctrl + K + D](http://www.faircom.com/ace/enl_26_vstips_t.php), it will auto format your markup and split the inline style to two lines.

However, i'd recommend separating the CSS out into an external style sheet or even putting it in a `<style>` tag within the page head.

```
<style type="text/css">
    table { border: thin solid #808080; padding: 3px 5px 7px 5px; vertical-align:top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use inline styles. put a CSS class on it and define the styles either in a `<style>` block or external CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a style sheet, if your main concern is the length of a style?

```
<table class="myStyle">
```

..is a lot more readable than..

```
<table style="border: thin solid #808080; padding: 3px 5px 7px 5px; vertical-align:top; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```