# ASPX Long Selectcommand

Tags: asp.net

I know this has to be posted somewhere and I'm probably not searching by the correct wording, but how do you break up a long selectcommand statement so you can see it all? Mine are running off the page and they're hard to read.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about query text in code or the query text in a SelectCommand of an `asp:SqlDataSource` tag on the ASPX page?

Comment: In the query text in a SelectCommand of an asp:SqlDataSource tag on the ASPX page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065040/how-can-i-split-an-attribute-value-onto-two-lines

Answer (score 0):

If you're using c#, you can do this like so:

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TopicsTitle,TopicContents,UserName,Avatar,NumberOfPost,uPoints,uType " +
                                 "FROM Topic, Registration " +
                                "WHERE Topic.Category ='" + ilblTopic.Text + "'" +
                                  "AND LastPostDate ='" + DateTime.Parse("...") + "'");
```

Bonus: please use a [parameterized query.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string builder to create a long strings.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("SELECT field1, field2, field3 as Field3_Something,");
sb.Append(field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9");
sb.Append(FROM table JOIN table2 AS TNS ON TNS.id = table.id");
sb.Append(" WHERE something = 1");
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString());
```